# Maven profiles basic datasource, jee:jndi-lookup

Tags: spring, maven-2, profile, pom.xml

I have a project with spring and maven. I found that using profiles, maven could change the properties of the data source. But what if in production the datasource is with a lookup like this, how to do the profiles for this: one with a basic datasource and the other a jee lookup.

```
 <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSourcejndi" jndi-name="jdbc/BGGDS"
      default-value="null" resource-ref="true"/>
```

This is how the profiles are in the pom.xml

```
<profiles>
         <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <hibernate.dialect>org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</hibernate.dialect>
                <jdbc.driver>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</jdbc.driver>
                <jdbc.url>jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/test</jdbc.url>
                <jdbc.username>sa</jdbc.username>
                <app.datasource>dataSource</app.datasource>
                <jdbc.password />
                <jdbc.isolation />
            </properties>
        </profile>

       <profile>
            <id>hudson</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <hibernate.dialect>org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</hibernate.dialect>
                <jdbc.driver>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</jdbc.driver>
                <jdbc.url>jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/othertest</jdbc.url>
                <app.datasource>dataSource</app.datasource>
                <jdbc.username>sa</jdbc.username>
                <jdbc.password />

            </properties>
        </profile>

</profiles>
```

and this the configutarion of spring

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd">



    <!--Datasource pruebas" -->
        <bean id="dataSource" 
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driver}"
        p:url="${jdbc.url}"
        p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" />



    <!-- La definición del Factory de Session con Anotaciones -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="${app.datasource}" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <!--Pruebas
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>-->
                <!--Produccion-->
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="mappingResources">

            <list>
                <value>Test.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>

    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
        </property>
    </bean>



   <!--  Injected properties
    -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
        </list>
        </property>

    </bean>
```

And this work for normal datasources, but what if I need a lockup.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you should go for two Spring configuration files, for example data-access.xml and data-access-test.xml, and use the later in a testing context. You can of course mix this approach with profiles and filtering, pickup one or the other depending on the profiles, etc. There are actually infinite possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

I had a situation a few months back where I had a Spring enabled JNDI connection for running on the app server and a Spring enabled c3p0 pooled connection for a desktop debugger of the same app.

In order to accomplish this, I had a two separate spring configs for the db.  One for JNDI, and one for the local pooled version.  I used a separate "parent" config which included the appropriate configuration based upon a filtered property in the parent config.

Long story short, use the profile to set the configuration file that you will include into your parent spring file.

Answer (score 0):

A simple, but very powerful option is to package different files with your application, i.e. different Spring configuration files.